# How to output firebase database query into VueJs page

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, vue.js, vuejs2

Currently I am querying a Firebase database for the current users `username`. I would like the value to display on the page inside the `<template>` area. Looked through the docs but still new to Vue.

Everything will output into the console correctly, I am just unsure of the next step to reference inside the `<template>` using moustache handles eg. `{{ user.username }}`

```
  data() {
    return {
      userName: ''
    }
  },
  methods: {
    getName: function() {
      var userId = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;
      return firebase.database().ref('users/' +
        userId).on('value', function(snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.val()) {
          var obj = snapshot.val();
          var userName = snapshot.val().username;
          console.log('username:', userName)
        }
      });
    }
  }
```

**Template**

```
<template>
 <span>{{ user.username }} (Output result of var userName here)</span>
</template>
```

Comment: I've never used vueJS, but have you tried `{{ userName }}` ?

Comment: You don't have a `user` data item. You have `userName`. You should probably set it in your `.on` callback, taking care to have `this` set properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting the username, but you are not updating the vue instance object (the `data` object). You can call `vueInstance.$set(vueInstance, 'propertyName', newPropertyValue);` to update it ([more details here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Change-Detection-Caveats)):

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      message: 'Hello Vue.js!',
      userName: ''
    }
  },
  methods: {
    getName: function() {
      var vueInstance = this;
      return setTimeout(function() {
        var userName = 'new username';
        vueInstance.$set(vueInstance, 'userName', userName);
        console.log('username:', userName)
      }, 2000);
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>

<div id="app">
  <span>{{ message }}</span><br>
  <span>`{{ userName }}´ (Output result of var userName here)</span><br>
  <button @click="getName">Click me and wait for 2 seconds, the username will be updated</button>
</div>
```

Comment: That makes sense! Thanks for the detailed response.

Answer (score 1):

To you can use {{ user.username }}, in your data you need put like that:

```
data(){
    return{
        user: { 
            username:  ' '
        }
    }
}
```

and you are not updating the right username instance, you can change this line:

```
var userName = snapshot.val().username;
```

for this:

```
this.username = snapshot.val().username;
```

Comment: Attempted this but receive the following error: `TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'this.username = snapshot.val().username')`